# How to get the list of variables that appear in a boolean expression?

Tags: haskell, boolean, pattern-matching

Hello I need help in constructing a function that returns the variables of a Boolean expression. I am trying to get the pattern but I can't fund a general approach that works with all test cases.

Here is the code

```
module BoolExpr (Variable, BoolExpr(..), evaluate) where
import Data.List
import System.IO

type Variable = Char
data BoolExpr = T
 |F
 |Var Variable
 |Not BoolExpr
 |And BoolExpr BoolExpr
 |Or BoolExpr BoolExpr
 deriving(Show)


--this is my attempt 
variables :: BoolExpr -> [Variable]
variables T = []
variables F = []
variables (Var e1)= [e1]
variables (And (Var e1) (Var e2))=variables (Var e1) ++variables (Var e2)
variables (Or (Var e1) (Var e2))=variables (Var e1) ++variables (Var e2)
variables ( And (Var e1) (Or (Var e2)(Var e3)) ) = variables (Var e1) ++ variables (Var e2) ++ variables (Var e3) 
variables (xy)=variables x ++ variables y
variables _ = []
```

Some testcases and their desired output

```
> variables T
""

> variables (Or T F)
""

> variables (Var 'a')
"a"

> variables (And (Var 'a') (Or (Var 'c') (Var 'b')))
"abc"

> variables (And (Var 'a') (Or (Var 'a') (Var 'a')))
"a"
```

But if more than three variables are used or so, the function will fail. I can't make it in a general form

Comment: Try to match on `variables (And e1 e2)` instead of `variables (And (Var e1) (Var e2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern matching is *too* specific. For example you write a clause:

```
variables (And (Var e1) (Var e2)) = …
```

and thus you restrict yourself to an `And` where the operands are values wrapped in a `Var` data constructor. But that is not necessaary. We can just write this as:

```
variables (And e1 e2) = …
```

so then `e1` and `e2` are `BoolExpr`s that can be constructed with all possible data constructors. We thus can define the function as:

```
variables :: BoolExpr -> [Variable]
variables T = []
variables F = []
variables (Var e1) = [e1]
variables (And e1 e2) = variables e1 ++ variables e2
variables (Or e1 e2) = variables e1 ++ variables e2
variables (Not e) = variables e
```

Note that a variable will occur *multiple* times if it is part of the expression multiple times. You thus might want to pass the result through a *uniqness filter* if you want a list of *unique* variables. You furthermore might want to sort the result as well.

We can do that by defining a function that works on top of the variables, like:

```
uniqVariables :: BoolExpr -> [Variable]
uniqVariables e = _ (variables e)
```

where `_` is something you need to fill in. I leave this as an exercise.

Comment: It's worth adding that this approach will fail some of the testcases because a variable will appear multiple times in the output list if it appears multiple times in the expression. Of course that's not difficult to fix, but it's worth mentioning that some changes are needed before it does exactly as specified.

Comment: @RobinZigmond that would perhaps be better as a comment to the _question_. The most practical solution is to switch from `[]` to `Data.Set` as the result container, not to introduce some ad-hoc duplicates removal method.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you meant `variables e` not `variable e`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I agree about `Set` but I feel it wouldn't have been appropriate to mention that as a direct response to the question when the issue was with how the OP was trying to write the original (list-based) function. Especially as I would guess this type signature has been specified by the class tutor. I personally still think my comment is more appropriate to this answer because I'm basically saying "the answer is correct, but needs a little tweaking in order to exactly fulfill the given test cases".